# MVC View Search and string id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got some strange behavior happening that I don't understand.  My primary key of a table is a string, thus I'm using a string as my id the mvc action.

My url looks like this:

```
 http://localhost:3333/profile/edit/fsdfsdsdfsdfff
```

The action looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
```

I checked and made sure that the id variable is not null.  It is properly populated.

My route config looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default2",
            url: "Profile/Edit/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Edit" }

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is the error:

> The view 'fsdfsdsdfsdfff' or its master was not found or no view
>   engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/Profile/fsdfsdsdfsdfff.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Profile/fsdfsdsdfsdfff.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/fsdfsdsdfsdfff.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/fsdfsdsdfsdfff.vbhtml

Why in the world is using my route value to find a view?  It might be worth noting that the id value in the action is a string.  If I change it to an int, it works fine.  What gives?

Comment: It looks like you don't require a custom route in the first place, your default route will serve your purpose.

Comment: You would think so, but I added the custom route to fix the problem in the first place.

Comment: I still stand in my point, you dont need that custom route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an issue with routing it is an issue with finding a view. When you call

```
return View(id);
```

You are actually calling a method, where parameter is a view name. You don't encounter this issue when you are using `int` parameter, because it does not have an overload with single integer parameter.

In order to fix the issue, you should convert the string parameter to object, in this case the correct overload will be used:

```
return View((object)id);
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It show the the problem has solved already.

You may also try like below to solve the problem.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    return View("ViewName", id);
}
```

By giving the view name it will goes to correct page.